# 90's movie. Boy wishes for new dad. Cool spaceship bed

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've only seen this movie once, and it was over twenty years ago, so bear with me and my lack of details.

- Movie was in English and looked to be new when I saw it
- Main character is a young boy, probably around eight or nine
- He *might* be the only child of a single mom (possibly has a sister)
- The cast was all white
- There's a legend or something about a local stone or statue in the park that grants wishes
- The boy wishes for his mom to find someone new and his wish is granted
- At the end of the movie the boy goes back to the statue to wish his mom and the new guy get married
- His mom and the guy find him asleep near the stone/statue late at night (I guess he ran away to make the wish)
- He has a sweet spaceship bunk bed thing where the top is the bed and below that is this whole cockpit setup with a bubble window and everything

Comment: agh...I've *seen* this!

Comment: @JohnP The *hell* is it then! Don't leave me in suspense!

Comment: If I could remember I'd post it. I can ***see*** the couple and the statue! Damn you.

Comment: Only 90's movie I can think of is [Trading Mom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111470/). :(

Comment: @JohnP: Can you describe the statue maybe?

Comment: Anyone care to comment why this question is being close-voted? Answer do not make the question off-topic. The who "wish granting rock" seems to be fantasy even the genre of the film as a whole is not.

Comment: @Skooba I don't see how a wish granting rock makes this a fantasy work. We have such legends in real life. Was it confirmed in the movie that the statue made his mother get married again? Can you point to a related discussion about how such a minor point would make a work on topic?

Comment: @zabeus - "**His wish is granted"**. Seems fantastical to me.

Comment: @zabeus related meta [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11766/is-this-question-about-the-great-mouse-detective-on-topic) -- How is magically granting wishes not fantasy? We have legends about dragons, wizards, demons, all sorts of things but that doesn't make them any less fantasy.

Comment: @zabeus or this [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/is-the-story-id-question-that-turned-out-to-be-about-the-axe-commercial-on-topi?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be better

Comment: "His wish is granted" is part of the answer. I didn't consider the answer at all in my  vote, but still assumed that any such implication was presented as a serendipitous event, or ambiguous at best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the movie you're looking for is "Problem Child 2".  In this film, an 8 year old kid and his Dad move to a new town.  He tries to get his Dad together with the school nurse.

- **In English**: Yup.  Released in 1991.
- **The main character is an 8 year old boy**: Yup.
- **He might be the only child of a single mom (possibly has a sister)**: Single dad, and the nurse has a daughter his age.
- **The cast was all white**: The main cast on IMDB is all white.
- **There's a legend or something about a local stone or statue in the park that grants wishes**: That'd be the Navajo love rock.  Big rock with a glowing heart on it.
- **The boy wishes for his mom to find someone new and his wish is granted / At the end of the movie the boy goes back to the statue to wish his mom and the new guy get married**: The little boy and the nurses daughter wish for their parents to get together.
- **His mom and the guy find him asleep near the stone/statue late at night (I guess he ran away to make the wish)**: I recall the little boy and girl curled up together under the rock when they're found.
- **He has a sweet spaceship bunk bed thing where the top is the bed and below that is this whole cockpit setup with a bubble window and everything**: Judicious use of YouTube reveals that he does have this bed - until his room is redone to be entirely clown based.

Here's a YouTube clip of the rock, which might help jog your memory:

Someone from the art department has a [website](http://artsee1.com/pageslinked/TVP%20Production%20Problem%20Child%20II%20Paul%20And%20Mimi%20Roberts%20Artists%20Designers%20Televisionaries%20Artsee1.html) with several pictures of the bed:

[image][image]

Comment: The trailer has the bed about 30 seconds in: https://youtu.be/Qmvf4Jr0AEg?t=31s

Comment: That's an incredibly 90's trailer.  Also, watching a few minutes of this movie makes me realize why my Dad found it so annoying when I was a kid.  (I was 6 when it came out, so the child actors weren't bad)

Comment: Yeah, *Problem Child* and the sequel were verboten in my household because my mother didn't think much of glorifying bad behavior, and because she felt terms like "problem child" demonized children who generally just want attention and don't know how to do so appropriately (funnily enough, she ruled out Rugrats based on the title, but loved it once she watched it for the Peanuts-ish combination of adult reasoning and childish interpretation).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - And yet you've grown up to be such a well-adjusted individual :-)